# How can I remove icons from menus of QT apps?

Tags: icons, menu, vlc, qt

VLC, Skype, Clementine and Virtualbox (the four QT apps I use) all have icons in their menus. The rest of my system's menus are all iconless, How I like them.

I'm using 12.04.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/70153/how-to-disable-icon-on-menus-and-buttons-for-all-kde-applications (also unanswered). From quick googling this might be some bug in Ubuntu, as according archlinux forum i.e., Qt applications obey settings from gconf

Answer (score 0):

Icons in the menus is standard for Qt/KDE apps. In order for Qt apps to obey the gconf settings, the developers have to specifically code that in. You have no control over this, but it's not a bug in Ubuntu. It's behaviour by design from the app